# Alternative to the transil diode in an AC converter

Tags: dimmer, diode-clamp

Can I omit the transil diode (1.5KE68A1) in this 220V to 110V converter, or is it essential?  Is there is an alternative, such as a varistor or EPCOS switching spark gap?

[image]

[Circuit source.](https://www.tehnomagazin.com/Power-supply/220V-to-110V-step-down-circuit.htm)

Comment: It's your circuit, so why did you put it there? If it's not your circuit then where did you get the diagram and, was there an explanation?

Comment: this is the link:
https://www.tehnomagazin.com/Power-supply/220V-to-110V-step-down-circuit.htm

Comment: I suspect the transil is used as a zener diode, so it is required for correct operation. A varistor or spark gap won’t do. You could use a number of lower voltage rated transits to make up the 68V - eg: 2 33V devices would do at a pinch.

Comment: @maher471 have you read the article you linked? About the transil, it says `The Transil reduces the power dissipation through R3.` so it's not a thing that you can replace with a MOV, spark gap or whatever.

Comment: But i do not have such this component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage of TVS and R2 (180 kΩ) determine the charge rate of capacitor C1. This is how the voltage of C1 reaches the switch-on level of the DIAC approximately 7 ms. R1 (12 kΩ) discharges capacitor C1 at each zero crossing (at 10 ms intervals.) Thus, after each zero crossing, the 7 ms delay starts again. The TVS can be replaced with a 68 V Zener diode, its maximum current here is 10 mA. A Zener with a power rating of 1 W will be suitable here. Here, a Zener with a voltage higher than the TRIAC's turn-on voltage is definitely needed. The value of R2 also depends on this voltage. I didn't see how big the inductive load was, so I just chose one. The parallel resistor (R5) damps the oscillations of the switched-off coil, its value is not critical. One half of VG1 is grounded for simulation purposes only. This means, for example, that the UL voltage is relative to ground. In the actual circuit, this point should not be grounded.

[image]

[image]